# Creating a link to the details page

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to turn the output from

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
```

into a hyperlink which will display a details page depending on Id.

Here is the standard code for a link to the details page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id })
```

Any advice will be most welcome.

Thanks..

Comment: Not on a computer at the minute to check so won't post as answer, but I assume you can do: `@Html.ActionLink("@item.Name", "Details", new { id=item.Id })`

Comment: Thank's, solution worked without the  " "  being needed. 

    @Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Details", new { id=item.Id })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", new {item.Id})